# Image is unnecessarily displayed on <p:graphicImage> event though the image name from the resources directory is not given

Tags: image, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I have stored some images under the `webroot\resources\fileUpload\product_image\thumb` directory so that these images can be displayed on `<p:graphicImage>` as follows.

```
<p:graphicImage library="fileUpload" 
                name="product_image/thumb/13850470212653732655006325945389_4921.jpg" 
                alt="Whatever the product name is."/>
```

If the image name i.e `13850470212653732655006325945389_4921.jpg` is not given then, the image should not be displayed but it displays an image from the given URL.

```
<p:graphicImage library="fileUpload" 
                name="product_image/thumb/" 
                alt="Whatever the product name is."/>
```

The image URL on the web browser appears as follows.

```
/webroot/javax.faces.resource/product_image/thumb/.jsf?ln=fileUpload&v=13850470212653732655006325945389_4921
```

How does it pick up an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the resource filename matches `\d+(_\d+)`, then it's recognized as a versioned resource. This is a rarely used feature ([resource library versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11988418/) is more common). Concretely, you can have such a structure:

```
WebContent
 |-- resources
 |    `-- js
 |         `-- script.js
 |              |-- 1_0.js
 |              |-- 1_1.js
 |              `-- 1_2.js
 :
```

*(yes, `script.js` is here the **folder** name)*

And when you declare it as follows:

```
<h:outputScript name="js/script.js" />
```

then automatically the latest one, the `1_2.js`, will be served as per the following generated HTML output, provided a context path of `/context` and a JSF mapping of `*.xhtml`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/context/javax.faces.resource/scripts/script.js.xhtml?v=1_2"></script>
```

This all is specified in chapter 2.6.1.3 of [JSF specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jsf-2_2-fr-eval-spec/index.html).

You've there however a bit unfortunate corner case of using an extensionless folder with a trailing slash as resource name, which should IMO have failed, but it apparently is also accepted by Mojarra.

If you'd like to avoid this behavior, you need to use a different pattern as file name. E.g. use `-` instead of `_`, or use `_` as prefix or suffix, or bring in at least one alphabetic character.

Comment: Changing the file name disallowed the image to display, when a file name is empty. Off topic : the `alt` attribute of `<p:graphicImage>` does not display the alternate text, when an image is unavailable. Is there anything to look into it to display the alternate text? Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. The `alt` is only shown when the `src` is empty. In other words, when `<p:graphicImage name>` is `null` or empty. If an invalid resource is specified, it generates a `src="RES_NOT_FOUND"`. I'd add a conditional to omit `product_image/thumb/` if name is null or empty.